# Can I play the original Destiny on my XBox One with someone on XBox 360?

Tags: destiny, backwards-compatibility

There are questions similar to this, but none are helping me. I love the Destiny games. Always have. My Dad is looking to spend some video game time with me, and I thought this would be the perfect game for us to play together. Problem is, I have an Xbox One S and he has an Xbox 360. I know that there is backwards compatibility. If I get two copies of the Xbox 360 Destiny; one for each console, would the backwards compatibility feature allow us to play together? We both have Xbox Live. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to play the Xbox 360 version of Destiny on the Xbox One as it is not backward compatible at the moment.  See this [**full list of supported games**](https://www.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games).

Note, Xbox periodically add more games to their backward compatibility feature over time.  If Destiny would then become backward compatible you would be able to play together (with both platforms using the Xbox 360 version of the game).

Also, although not relevant to the backward compatible feature...

> Destiny does not support cross-platform play.

Source: [**Bungie Help Articles**](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/12219)